# React Native app downloaded from play store not working on android 9

Tags: react-native

I developed react native app in version 0.59. I tested with data cable on every device including android 9 app is working fine. I uploaded app to play store now my app working on every device except android 9. Also i uploaded single .apk file, generated multiple .apk files for different CPU architectures and lastly i generated android app bundle file and uploaded to play store but none of these methods works on android 9. My app installed on android 9 but didn't fetch data on home screen of my app. I used axios for data fetching.

Answer (score 0):

Add the codes in your main AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> .... <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"> ... </application> </manifest>
```